# Is it possible to call a Module function from inside a class that is also in that module

Tags: ruby

In this Ruby code:

```
Module M
  Class C < Struct.new(:param)
    def work
      M::helper(param)
    end
  end

  def helper(param)
    puts "hello #{param}"
  end
end
```

I get a "undefined method 'helper' for 'M:Module'" error when I try to run

```
c = M::C.new("world")
c.work
```

but calling `M::helper("world")` directly from another class works fine.  Can classes not call Module functions that are defined in the same Module they are defined in?  Is there a way around this other than moving the class outside of the module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to invoke `M::helper` you need to define it as `def self.helper; end`
For the sake of comparison, take a look at helper and helper2 in the following modified snippet

```
module M
  class C < Struct.new(:param)
    include M     # include module to get helper2 mixed in
    def work
      M::helper(param)
      helper2(param)
    end
  end

  def self.helper(param)
    puts "hello #{param}"
  end

  def helper2(param)
    puts "Mixed in hello #{param}"
  end
end

c = M::C.new("world")
c.work
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation of the difference between using self. and including the module.

Answer (score 4):

you should prepend module method with `self`:

```
module M
  class C < Struct.new(:param)
    def work
      M::helper(param)
    end
  end

  def self.helper(param)
    puts "hello #{param}"
  end
end
```

Comment: These weren't in the question, but `C.work` is called as a class method instead of instance method. Have you tried calling `M.helper("foo")`?

Answer (score 3):

`C` is trying to call `helper` on `M` when `helper` is not in `M`'s singleton class. Also, you keep saying that `helper` is a module function, when it is only a method. Making `helper` a module function will make the code work:

```
module M
  class C < Struct.new(:param)
    def work
      M::helper(param)
    end
  end

  module_function

  def helper(param)
    puts "hello #{param}"
  end
end
```

Including the module in the class will also work:

```
module M
  class C < Struct.new(:param)
    include M

    def work
      helper(param)
    end
  end

  def helper(param)
    puts "hello #{param}"
  end
end
```

In the first example, `helper` is put into `M`'s singleton class with `module_function`. The second example imports `M`'s methods into `C` so that `C` can use them. Another difference is that in the first, you will be able to call `M.helper` from anywhere in your code. In the second, you will be able to call `helper` from any instance of `C` in your code. To fix this, make `helper` private:

```
module M
  class C < Struct.new(:param)
    include M

    def work
      helper(param)
    end
  end

  private
  def helper(param)
    puts "hello #{param}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some explanation:

From [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html).

> A Module is a collection of methods and constants. The methods in a module may be instance methods or module methods. Instance methods appear as methods in a class when the module is included, module methods do not. **Conversely, module methods may be called without creating an encapsulating object, while instance methods may not. (See Module#module_function.)**

`self.methodname` inside a module creates a module method.

In this case when you invoke `M::helper` you actually doing `M.helper` when you look at it from a C++ developer's point of view. The receiver is Module object (an instance of ruby builtin type Module) in this case.

---

Other way to looking at this is to understand a receiver concept, every method call consists of a receiver and method name (+ optionally params and code block). Receiver can be a `Module object`, `Class object` or instance of a user defined class.

You can only invoke Module (or Class) methods on a Module (or Class) object. You can invoke any method (Module/Class/instance) on an instance.

If you want to invoke an instance method defined in a module then you must give it a receiver by `including` that module in some class and creating an instance of it.

So in this case another solution can be:

```
module MM
  def helper(param)
    puts "hello #{param}"
  end

  class ReceiverClass
    include MM           # add helper() to ReceiverClass
  end

  class C < Struct.new(:param)
    def work
      ReceiverClass.new.helper(param)
    end
  end
end

c = MM::C.new("world")
c.work
```